# Cursor disappears as soon as I login into Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

Cursor disappears as soon as I login into Ubuntu... How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens is your keyboard also ignored ?  ... to check hit ctrl-alt-t which if keyboard is working will open up a terminal window ... if this also fails then hit ctrl-alt-F2   which will take you to a console window login prompt ... Does it ?   If so then to return back hit ctrl-alt-F7 at which point your mouse and keyboard should be working fine again

If all of the above is true I also suffered from same issue which in my case was only triggered if I used the laptop trackpad ... avoiding trackpad usage did avoid this hanging issue ... On same machine where I had this issue on ubuntu 14.xx and 15.xx once I installed ubuntu 16.04 this problem disappeared for good

Please clue us in on your findings

Comment: Login prompt did not help solving this problem! Anyway after updating the version did help....Thank you so much